# How to expire ajax request link in PHP after certain Time Interval?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

my ajax function will execute automatically by setInterval().
here i used Cache:false so on every request the time stamp will sent. but in php file i want to set expire for that timestamp. if the request received with existing time stamp should not return value.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    myVar = setInterval("asdFunc()", 1000);
});

function asdFunc(){
 var date = new Date().getTime();
 $.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  cache:false,
  url:"rest.php",
  data:{lest:"data"},
  success:function(daa){
    $('.response').html(daa);
   }
 })
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="response">
 here will,
</div>
</html>
<script src="http://localhost/polt_s/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: Since the Client can alter JavaScript, you should not rely on Client time. Make your AJAX work with time on the Server.

Comment: so how can i achieve it, i need unique url for every request, but that unique url should expire after some time..

Comment: Use a session, since they are unique. Keep making AJAX requests, just test against Server time.

Comment: Thanks for response, i will try with session.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    setTimeout(asdFunc(), 1000); //check here in your code

     function asdFunc(){

        var date = new Date().getTime();

        $.ajax({

        type:"GET",

        cache:true, //cache = true, this will improve page performance

        url:"rest.php",

        data: {lest:"data"},

        success:function(daa){

            $('.response').html(daa);
        }
     })
  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, but by set cache:true how can i expire the link in PHP..?

Comment: Use setTimeout, to expire link after ceratin time.

Comment: cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')
Type: Boolean
If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already been requested by a GET.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i want to generate unique URL for Every request, in PHP need to expire that link after certain time interval.

Comment: Use PHP rand() function to generate random number and  assign that value to url.

Comment: Thanks i will try.